# Connection was aborted: SBA 2.0.2, Though the app works fine. The embedded TC console shows this error sporadically

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I am seeing the below trace sporadically while using the SBA (Spring Boot Admin) version 2.0.2. Just followed the steps here: https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/ 
Not sure about the source of this error and why the exception is thrown?

```
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1279) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:670) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flushBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:607) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flush(SocketWrapperBase.java:597) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:646) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.flush(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:169) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:252) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.flush(Http11Processor.java:1561) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:371) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:173) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:317) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:284) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:118) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:121) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:103) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:43) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:226) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler$HttpMessageConvertingHandler.sendInternal(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:200) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler$HttpMessageConvertingHandler.send(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:190) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.sendInternal(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:189) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.send(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:183) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter.send(SseEmitter.java:133) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler$SseEmitterSubscriber.send(ReactiveTypeHandler.java:366) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler$AbstractEmitterSubscriber.run(ReactiveTypeHandler.java:309) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

Comment: Which exception - "Connection was aborted"? Is than a generic IOException, or something else? I suspect you've missed some lines off the top. I'm guessing a stream is closed though, so you're trying to emit some content too early or too late in the page response, or after an error has already closed the stream.

Comment: This stack trace was seen while navigating the application. I am not quite sure about the SBA architecture. The triggering points and source of failure not sure. May be the architect who designed the SBA may have the better idea.

Comment: Here is the complete stack trace.